# MS Teams Chat Bot Custom Authorization

Tags: azure, authorization, botframework, microsoft-teams

Assumption:

- We have MS Teams internally at the customer side;
- We are using the **botframework-solution** deployed in Azure and the bots are registered with the Azure Bot Channel Registration;
- We have a service principal for every Bot channel registration.

Basically the flow of how the user interact with the Chatbot is :

- The user log-in in Teams with the company credential
- The user interact with the Chat Bot
- Within the Chat Bot implementation we have a Teams Middleware to get the user information and use those info to interact with several on-premise services.

My question is about how the Authorization happens between the Chatbot, Teams and AD. We are using the configuration of the service principals as described in the docs, setting the **redirectUri** to *https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect* and **signInAudience** to *AzureADMultipleOrgs*. Basically we are using the Authentication Provider that as per documentation is "out-of-the-box".

My question is, do we have to use that Authentication Provider (token.botframework.com) or is possible to use a different Auth Provider with different redirect uri and so on, keeping the same flow that we have without adding any other kind of Client Authentication (AuthCard for example)? Also because I'm not sure using MultiTenant signInAudience is actually compliant with the security rules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could build your own authentication logic if you want using [Sign In action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#signin). Please take a look at [Auth Sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node).

Comment: I'm not talking about user authentication, but about Bot Framework authorization : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-bot-framework-faq?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#app-registration.   Here looks like that anyway I have to setup the MultiOrg setting and use the botframework provider. Because actually my user is already authenticate with Teams directly.